# `127.0.0.1' is not a valid domain

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I have a rails application running on Nginx server and unicorn as an application server. All of the requests process fine but I am getting an error of `127.0.0.1' is not a valid domain after every request. Any ideas of where I should check?

I have tried to add the domain name in nginx server settings which was localhost before.

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/home/deploy/project/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.mydomain;

    root /home/deploy/project/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

[Here is the stack trace of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh5TY.png)

Comment: shouldn't be related to you rails app, this is probably Nginx listener config issue.
can you add Nginx conf (server)?
just a guess, where you have listen 127.0.0.1:80; change it to listen 80;

Comment: I added the relevant configurations in the question. listen is set to 80. @ItamarLavender Do you see any other issue in the conf?

Comment: I don't think wildcards are possible there.
If this is your only vhost then try using:
server_name  _;